# comparing query results from within the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

RDBMS SQL Server, T-SQL

Consider a table that links information from two different tables: Articles and Categories. This table contains for each Article one or several entries containing the ID of the Categories the Article belongs to. Therefore, a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ARTICLEID = X
```

returns 1 to n results.

I am looking to build a query which allows me to compare Articles that have the exact same combination of Categories. I've been trying with INTERSECT, but that does not return any rows. An example:

```
ARTICLEID  CATEGORYID

    1  1
    1  2
    1  4
    2  1
    2  4
    3  1
    3  2
    3  4
    4  2
    4  4
    5  1
    5  2
    5  4
```

The query for `ARTICLEID = 1` should return 3 and 5, for `ARTICLEID = 3` should return 1 and 5, et cetera.

Comment: Can you show us the query you've tried?

Comment: See [Proper Relational Division With Sets](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/07/02/Proper-Relational-Division-With-Sets.aspx)

Comment: I tried (among many other things) select TagID from articletags where articleid=166 INTERSECT select TagID from articletags as articletags_1 where articleid<>166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITed: This should work

```
with temp as
(
    select a.*, b.articleid as bart, 1 as cnt from tableName a left join
    tableName b on a.CATEGORYID=b.CATEGORYID where a.articleid=XXX
)
select bart from temp where bart<>articleid group by bart having sum(cnt) =
(select count(*) from tableName where articleid=XXX)
```

Just run this exact query, changing only the XXX to whatever articleID that you need to match. It should work.

Comment: If I read this correctly, this would return any set of records where categoryID is identical and the number of categories is the same. I understand the approach, but the query returns no results on my table.

Comment: Yeh...not having a table to test it on I made a few mistakes. I've edited the query and I think this version should work.

Comment: Either way, you understand the approach so if it doesn't work you can make a couple edits and it should. have fun~

Comment: returns "The multi-part identifier a.articleid could not be found".

Comment: ah, found it. The last a.articleid=XXX should simply read articleid instead. Thanks.

Comment: We're almost home. Consider:

select * from Articles where ArticleID in (with temp as (select a.*, b.articleid as sameAs, 1 as cnt from articletags a left join articletags b on a.tagID=b.tagID where a.articleid=157 ) select sameAs from temp where sameAs<>articleid group by sameAs having sum(cnt) = (select count(*) from articletags where articleid=157))

Comment: Fixed that, it was just in the wrong order. Thanks again Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT ART.ID, 
          ART.COLUMN2, 
          ART.COLUMN3,
          CAT.ID,
          CAT.COLUMN2,
          CAT.COLUMN3,
          ART_CAT.CAT_ID
   FROM   ARTICLE ART,
          CATEGORY CAT,
          ARTICLE_CATEGORY ART_CAT
   WHERE  ART.ID = 1
          ART_CAT.CAT_ID = ART.ID
```

I'm sure that query has some holes in it but that should give you a starting point.

**EDIT:** Corrected join per the last part of your question. (Didn't see it the first time around.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Right Join`?

```
create table category
(
    Categoryid int
)

insert into category(Categoryid)values(1)
insert into category(Categoryid)values(2)
insert into category(Categoryid)values(3)
insert into category(Categoryid)values(4)
insert into category(Categoryid)values(5)

create table articles
(
    Articleid int,
    Categoryid int
)

insert into articles(Articleid, Categoryid)values(1, 1)
insert into articles(Articleid, Categoryid)values(1, 2)
insert into articles(Articleid, Categoryid)values(1, 4)
insert into articles(Articleid, Categoryid)values(2, 1)
insert into articles(Articleid, Categoryid)values(2, 4)

Select c.Categoryid
From
(
    Select * from articles where Articleid = 2
)a
right Join category c on c.Categoryid = a.Categoryid


drop table articles
drop table category
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. The query returns no results, and you lost me at a.Categoryid is null.

Comment: This applies to a scenario with two tables. My scenario concerns a single table.

Comment: a SELECT DISTINCT CategoryID would give you that; basically a set of values 1-n.

Comment: `Select distinct(categoryid) from articles` ?

Comment: I think you're completely missing the point here. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.if everything is integer.

```
with mycte as
(
select articleid,count(*) as cnt,sum(categoryid) as sm,max(categoryid) mx,min(categoryid) mn
from mytable
group by articleid
) 
select mc.articleid,mc1.articleid from mycte mc inner join mycte mc1 on mc.sm = mc1.sm 
and mc.mn = mc1.mn
and mc.mx = mc1.mx
and mc.cnt = mc1.cnt
and mc.articleid <> mc1.articleid
```

if you need them in one line then you do not need to join the cte but instead try row number partition by cnt,sm,mx,mn order by articleid..This will give you the data..

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that eventually worked:

with temp as (select a.*, b.articleid as sameAs, 1 as cnt from articletags a left join articletags b on a.tagID=b.tagID where a.articleid=XXX ) select * from Articles where ArticleID in (select sameAs from temp where sameAs<>articleid group by sameAs having sum(cnt) = (select count(*) from articletags where articleid=XXX)))

XXX being the ArticleID passed in. The result is a set of records that share the same articletags as the ones for ArticleID.